# Backpack Laravel : How to store to multiple tables?

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

The product table is related to the subscription table (1-n)
In the createoperation method in the ProductController I have several fields to add, no problem with the product fields, they are inserted into the product table correctly.

Just I need to know how check subscriptions are added in subscription table with current product id

This is a product form

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFvzm.png)

Comment: Edit your question with appropriate code from controller and probably from migration file.

Comment: Indeed, can't help much. 
Please post your relation definition, and the "relevant fields" (please don't post full controllers) for this question. 

Also I would advise to have a look at https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/community-forum for similar issues. 

https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/6.x/crud-how-to#hasmany-1-n-relationship may also help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.